# Better Free tool for AKKA-JAVA performance monitoring

Tags: akka, monitoring

Please help me out with the various free tools available for monitoring the AKKA-JAVA application.We are in need of measuring the performance.

Comment: What aspect of performance do you need to monitor?

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: We have developed an application in AKKA-JAVA,we need to track the number  of actors being initiated,mail box size,memory utilization and number of dead letters,so in-order to track and monitor these are there any tools existing?

Comment: Kamon should do the trick, can be a fiddly setting up with Java, mainly due to lack of docs, but I've managed it so give it a try and ask some more questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The same question was already asked [debugging-akka-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191285/debugging-akka-performance/27191802#27191802)

Beside [Kamon](http://kamon.io) you have whole bunch of jvm monitoring tools starting from JMX, [Metrics](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/) [StatsD](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fetsy%2Fstatsd%2F&ei=uRqIVKCHIZLgarzbgnA&usg=AFQjCNGvSloZ76S1fz3xqxVF4qg3uGZtMQ&sig2=EGQZg78oG1LTvQNYVNk0TA&bvm=bv.81456516,d.d24) and so on.